# Spark JavaPairRDD behaviour when file gets updated

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have one use case where I am joining data between one file and stream data.
For this purpose I read the data in file as JavaPairRDD and cache it.

But the catch is that the file is going to be updated periodically in 3-4 hours.
Now my doubt is do I have to read the file again and re create the JavaPairRDDs to reflect the changes in file or is it taken care of by Spark already i.e. whenever the file gets updated are the RDDs recreated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD's in Spark are designed to be immutable, if the underlying data changes the values in the RDD will not change unless it is uncached/unpersisted/uncheckpointed. In general Spark assumes that the backing data for an RDD doesn't change, so you would likely be better of instead creating a new RDD (or treating both as streams).

Comment: So if instead of reading my file as JavaPairRDD, I read it as JavaDStream object then I don't have to explicitly  reread the data again right ?

Comment: Well you will need to change how the data is written to be in a way that Spark Streaming can handle it (e.g no overwrites).

Comment: My files are going to be deleted and then re created that means I don't have that luxury. I will have to reread data it seems.